# How to test in Karma without require.context

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-webpack

So I spent a long time in React land, with Jest as my test runner/environment. 
Flash forward to new job, and we're unit testing an Angular 8 app w/ Karma.

Much to my dismay, I come to find the default config for Angular, and every single guide out there suggests something close to this line:

```
const context = require.context('../src/app', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

So when I update a file within my app, Angular CLI/Webpack have to rebuild whatever, and then it re-executes my entire f-ing test suite, which is thousands of tests, again.

I'm looking around and I see that Karma understands the concept of finding and watching files, but it seems as if that would never work given this approach.

Problem is we need to run this code to setup the environment:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

getTestBed().resetTestEnvironment();
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
```

Anybody have differential file watching / test running in Angular w/ Karma? If so, how it do???

Is there an easy way to run this setup code similar to Jest's [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array)?

Relevant Karma config (I don't use NG CLI, test.ts has the content above):

```
    frameworks: ['parallel', 'jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      require('ts-loader'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-webpack'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('karma-parallel'),
    ],

    files: [{ pattern: './test/index.ts', watched: false }],

    preprocessors: {
      './test/index.ts': ['webpack'],
    },
    webpack: karmaConfig(),

    webpackMiddleware: {
      stats: 'errors-warnings',
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three solutions here I think:

1) Use Jest instead for Angular testing [(It's possible!)](https://blog.angularindepth.com/integrate-jest-into-an-angular-application-and-library-163b01d977ce)

2) Use [WallabyJS](https://wallabyjs.com/) which can run behind the scenes and only execute changed tests. We use this and it's excellent.

3) Use `fdescribe` and `fit` to precisely target tests

Comment: Thank you! So it is our shared understanding then that this is not possible w/ straight Karma? fdescribe and fit works, but you don't get around webpack having to do whatever expensive magic it does to rebuild the require.context.

Comment: I added a small karma snippet above, I could easily change the `files` array to let it read all tests, but prob is the setup code.

Comment: I want to switch to Jest, or even Wallaby (will investigate more), but I don't enjoy the idea of rewriting or touching every test file; Our current solution "works", but I figured if I could make a few config changes and make the tdd experience much better, i'd take that o_O

Comment: Afraid not, there's an open issue for it but no progress since 2017.

I can advocate Wallaby if you're looking to enhance your experience and making as few changes as possible. It should just work out of the box.

Comment: I'll also throw in that if its a brand new project, maybe it's worth looking into using [Bazel](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/05/14/build-your-angular-application-with-bazel/) instead of Webpack. Once your first slow build succeeds, the rest are extremely fast.